# Efficient computation of $BX=A$ when LU factorization of $A$ is given

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack

First, $AX=B$ is solved, so I have the LU factorization of $A$ computed already.

Now I need to solve $BX=A$. Is there any way to reuse this information (LAPACK `gesv` was used to compute LU of $A$)?

Comment: I assume you solve for $X$? And what are the dimensions of $A$, $B$ and $X$?

Comment: @fibonatic right, matrix is square, dimension can be several thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question amounts to asking which is the optimal solution strategy for computing $X,Y$ such that 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
AX &= B\\
BY &= A
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $A, B$ are generic square dense matrices.
Apart from the observation that if $A$ and $B$ are non singular, then $Y=X^{-1}$, I do not see any particular reason for which the knowledge of $X$ should help in the computation of $Y$. But I'd love to be contradicted on this.